# Simple Lineal Regression with inputs function in R Shiny: problem with eval

Tags: r, input, eval, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I´m trying to build a Simple lineal regresion app with R shiny, but when I execute it, it show me the following error:
[image]

It doesn´t found the object and I don´t know why. The fragment code where is the error is:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Analisis de Regresion"), 
  sidebarPanel(
    #Eleccion de variable x
    p("Selecciona la primera variable a comparar"),
    selectInput(inputId = "varX", label = "Variable eje X", multiple = FALSE, choices = list("NumBusquedas", "FrecuenciaAsistente", "FrecuenciasCorreos", "NumMensajes", "FreqDiscover", "NumUsosApp", "NumPublicidad","NumSuscripciones","NumBusquedasYoutube")),
```

Where is my error? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The object `varX`can't be found by Shiny, so the problem is caused by either:

- You did not define it properly
  or
- The object is outside of the scope of the function that aims to use
  it

Double check the `InputId` for your input - is it named `varX`?

Comment: Yes, the error was in the input. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what was going without seeing your server code. I was wondering if you access/call the variable "varX" in the right way. You can access the input variable within the server using either `input$varX` or `input[["varX"]]`.

Comment: Yes, it´s just that. Thank you!! :)

Comment: Sounds great. I noticed you are new here and I would suggest your reading this post below which might be helpful. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419 @ María del Mar Soriano Jerez